# Will core training in off days be helpful or harmful to my main training?

Tags: weightlifting, core

I'm doing stronglifts 5x5. I workout at Mon, Wed, Fri.

I realized from my previous program that my core was very weak in compraed to other parts. If I added extra core workout in the rest days would it be beneficial or would it interfere with the rest of muscles?

Answer (score 1):

Rip suggests that its not necessary to add core work to the program because you are heavily using your core to brace in OHP, Squat, Deadlift and Row. However, this doesn't mean you will develop washboard abs doing the routine, there isn't enough volume for that.

If you want to build and grow your abdominal muscles, you need to add core-focused movements in the 10-20 rep range. Popular core exercises at the moment are:

- AB wheel
- Captains Chair/Hanging Leg Raises
- Weighted Plank